# How to connect a Linode S3 Bucket

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

we have a S3 Bucket at Linode which should be compatible with Amazon
The access with sm3cmd and S3 Browser work.

If I try to create a Stage in Snowflake I need to use following notation
s3://eu-central-1.linodeobjects.com
If I try to get access I get the following Error

*"Failure using stage area. Cause: [The authorization header is malformed; the region 'us-west-1' is wrong; expecting 'us-east-1' (Status Code: 400; Error Code: AuthorizationHeaderMalformed)] "*

1. Can Snowflake access S3 compatible Buckets like Linode Object Storage in general?
2. Can I change the used URL ?  Snowflake need a notation like S3://   but maybe it doesn't work in that way.  I also try to use the Bucket in the URL like
   s3://.eu-central-1.linodeobjects.com  ( like mentioned in Linode)

Thank you very much

Comment: It is interesting that the error would be region-related (the region 'us-west-1' is wrong; expecting 'us-east-1') like we are not creating the stage in the same region as the buckets.  What region are the buckets created in?  Just to rule out any region caching issues, I would also try a stage name that is completely unique and never been used to test.  If all that seems well, then perhaps the error is just misleading.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. We use a snowflake trial account so the stage name is unique. The linode bucket is located in eu-central-1  as the snowflake accout is located in aws_eu-central-1.  I am not sure if maybe this can be the problem? So otherwise i can not see any realy region isues.

Answer (score 0):

To access data placed in AWS S3 bucket from Snowflake - you need to create an external stage.
How to create one, detail [here](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/data-load-s3-create-stage.html#external-stages)
You need to have AWS IAM role already configured with the required policies and permissions to access your external S3 bucket

Snowflake does not support AWS S3 bucket access via Linode platform.

Comment: Ok Thank you very much for your answer kind regards Andreas